# How to use smartphones back button as webview back button?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, oncreate, onbackpressed

I recently started to program with Android studio, I came across a problem. I created a Webview application, and I would like to press the back button on the smartphone once you go back to the previously viewed page, while pressing it twice in a row will exit the application.
For now I only managed to lock the back button. Do you have any advice? I am attaching the code written so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage `onKeydown()` method, It goes like this...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (web.canGoBack())
                    web.goBack();
                else
                    finish();
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

By doing this you will be able to manage back press of website.
Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I have two errors now: mwebView (Can not resolve symbol 'mWebView') and event (Can not resolve symbol 'event'). How can I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: `mWebView` is your Webview object which `web` in your case..! I have updated according to your requirement, please try now.

Comment: @Simone.P Solved or not?